# Convert URLs inside CSS files to absolute ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

#### Background:

I'm creating a simple archiving method for web pages. I have downloaded some web pages along with their files (`css`, `js`, etc.). Now, using jQuery, I can manipulate links in the HTML file to point at the links in my server and it works for all the images, JavaScript and CSS files. However, in some situations, CSS files might refer to some images or fonts. I have parsed the links inside them as well but I don't know how to change these URLs. I looked around to see if there's something like the base URL for CSS files but couldn't find any.

### Question:

Is there any way for me to change the URLs inside the CSS files so that they point to content inside my server?

For example:

`background: url('graphic.png');`

To

`background: url('http://myserver.com/view/content?url=http://theirserver.com/graphic.png');`

Comment: Do you mean other than one by one by hand?

Comment: If you download the images and css, and keep them in a directory structure that mirrors the original site then the existing relative urls in the css will work, no?

Comment: Please re-define the question, I really don't understand it. Are you talking about search & replace in a text editor? What is the desired effect you are after, and what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @SteveAllison exactly. Base for urls is the location of CSS file

Comment: @SteveAllison That's a problem for me. I'm not using simple file system to retrieve content. It's more complicated than that.

Comment: @Mr.Web Yep. I want to do this using programs.

Comment: @JohanBouveng I don't know how else to describe. I want to use jQuery to dynamically change the URLs inside the CSS files in user's browser. Which part of it don't you understand? Maybe I can explain that part.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this will work for you?

```
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href','http://baseurl.com/'+this.href);
});
```

This takes place in the DOM, in the users browser, NOT in the CSS files.

Comment: This is what I'm doing now but it works for the HTML. I want to do this for CSS files.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following script to convert relative URL's to absolute URL's

```
function getFullURL(url) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    return a.href;
}
```